# Query on Sql Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have three tables.

> tblLink: (LinkId, LinkName, GroupId, ,SubGroupId)
>             GroupId and SubGroupId are foreign key in tblGroup and tblSubGroup
>   tblGroup: (GroupId, GroupName)
>   tblSubGroup: (SubGroupId, SubGroupName)

in tblLink SubGroupId is allowed Null but GroupId is Mandatory.

I want to fetch LinkName, GroupName, SubGroupName for every LinkId in tblLink
I have written a query

> SELECT L.LinkName, G.GroupName, SG.SubGroupName FROM tblLink L 
>                                           Left Join 
>                                                        tblSubGroup SG
>                                           ON
>                                                       (L.SubGroupId=SG.SubGroupId)
>                                           Inner Join
>                                                       tblGroup G
>                                           ON
>                                                       (L.GroupId=G.GroupId)

If there is no subgroup for some LinkId I want to show **NotExist** instead of **Null**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
    L.LinkName, G.GroupName, 
    ISNULL(SG.SubGroupName, 'NotExist') AS SubGroupName
FROM
    Link L
....
```

Comment: You can use COALESCE to do that (instead of ISNULL), just makes your query more portable.

Comment: @Technowise: beware implicit datatype conversion then... if SubGroupName is varchar(5) or char(50), it could be cast to varchar(8) to match the literal NotExist. With ISNULL it stays as per SubGroupName datatype. Portable SQL = changing contract?

Comment: @Technowise, what do you mean by portable here. What is COALESCE, Please Elaborate.